# Historical Market Capitalization Data via quantmod?

Tags: r, quantmod

Is it possible to get historical market capitalization data via the quantmod package?

**Updated:**

Given Yahoo for example only provide market cap as of today, i wonder is it ok to try infer historical market caps by:

[market_cap_today]/[adjusted_price] = [share_volume]

And then use [share_volume] to get the market cap for last week via:

[share_volume]*[adjusted_price_last_week] = [market_cap_last_week]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantmod package can only provide access to data if external data providers make it available. I don't believe Yahoo Finance, Google Finance, etc provide historical market capitalization, so the answer to your question is "no".